# byte[] to long in JNI

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I have a function to convert byte[] to long in java like this. The length of the array (byte[]) can be 4, 6 or 8 bytes.

```
public long toLong(byte[] dtIn) {
    try {
        return Long.parseLong(new String(dtIn).trim());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is there a function that is the same as the function above in JNI (C language).?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jlong toLong(jbyte *dtIn) {
    return strtol((const char*)dtIn, NULL, 10);
}
```

Example:

```
jbyte din[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38};
return toLong(din);
```

Result:
    12345678 (same with java code)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like following in JNI C.

```
unsigned long int l = pSrc[0] | (pSrc[1] << 8) | (pSrc[2] << 16) | (pSrc[3] << 24);
```

Here pSrc is the source byte array.

Comment: Does Android, as a Linux-based system, not have 8-byte longs?